# how can I connect database to insert, update, delete android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm doing an android studio project about a multiple choice test application, and I'm having the problem that I can't connect to the database with the user interface for editing, I find out that the error may be caused by the function: public My SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance() below has not been used to get database instances. But I still don't know why it's not used. Here are the classes that I see as possibly related to this error. So if you have any ideas, please help me with a solution. Thank you so much.

Here is my UserDatabaseAdapter:

```
package com.example.app_onthi_pmp.updatecauhoi;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserDatabaseAdapter{
    static ArrayList<UserModel> users=new ArrayList<>();
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CauHoi.sqlite";
    static final String TABLE_NAME = "CauHoi";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "UserDatabaseAdapter";
    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;
    // Context of the application using the database.
    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private static DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    private final Context context;


    public UserDatabaseAdapter(Context _context)
    {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    // Method to open the Database
    public UserDatabaseAdapter open () throws SQLException
    {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // Method to close the Database
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }

    // method returns an Instance of the Database
    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()//android studio said that method never used
    {
        return db;
    }

    // method to insert a record in Table
    public String insertEntry(String ma_de, String ques, String a, String b, String c, String d, String ans,String cauCanLuuY)
    {

        try {


            ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each column.
            newValues.put("MaDe", ma_de);
            newValues.put("CauHoi", ques);
            newValues.put("A", a);
            newValues.put("B", b);
            newValues.put("C", c);
            newValues.put("D", d);
            newValues.put("Ans", ans);
            newValues.put("CauCanLuuY", cauCanLuuY);

            // Insert the row into your table
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, newValues);
            Log.i(" inserted: ", String.valueOf(result));
            Utils.showToast(this.context.getApplicationContext(), "Info Saved! Total questions: "+getRowCount());
            db.close();

        }catch(Exception ex) {
        }
        return "ok";
    }

    // method to get all Rows Saved in Table
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    public static ArrayList<UserModel> getRows() throws JSONException {

        users.clear();
        UserModel user;
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor datacauhoi = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null,null, null, null, null,null);
        while (datacauhoi.moveToNext()) {

            user=new UserModel();
            user.setMa_de(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("soDe")));
            user.setQues(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("CauHoi")));
            user.setA(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("CauHoiA")));
            user.setB(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("CauHoiB")));
            user.setC(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("CauHoiC")));
            user.setD(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("CauHoiD")));
            user.setAns(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("DapAn")));
            user.setCauCanLuuY(datacauhoi.getString(datacauhoi.getColumnIndex("CauCanLuuY")));
            users.add(user);
        }
        datacauhoi.close();
        return users;
    }

    // method to delete a Record in Tbale using Primary Key Here it is ID
    public int deleteEntry(String ID)
    {
        String where="ID=?";
        int numberOFEntriesDeleted= db.delete(TABLE_NAME, where, new String[]{ID}) ;
        Toast.makeText(this.context.getApplicationContext(),"Deleted Successfully : "+numberOFEntriesDeleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return numberOFEntriesDeleted;
    }

    // method to get Count of Total Rows in Table
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(this.context.getApplicationContext(),"Total added: "+cursor.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    // method to Truncate/ Remove All Rows in Table
    public void truncateTable()
    {
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "1", null);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Table Data Truncated!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // method to Update an Existing Row in Table
    public void  updateEntry(String ID, String MaDe, String CauHoi, String CauA, String CauB, String CauC, String CauD, String DapAn, String CauCanLuuY)
    {
        ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
        updatedValues.put("soDe", MaDe);
        updatedValues.put("CauHoiA", CauA);
        updatedValues.put("CauHoiB", CauB);
        updatedValues.put("CauHoiC", CauC);
        updatedValues.put("CauHoiD", CauD);
        updatedValues.put("DapAn", DapAn);
        updatedValues.put("CauCanLuuY", CauCanLuuY);
        updatedValues.put("CauHoi", CauHoi);
        String where="ID = ?";
        db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,updatedValues, where, new String[]{ID});
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Updated!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and here is my database:

```
package com.example.app_onthi_pmp.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
public class dbCauHoi extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public dbCauHoi(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    //not return
    public void QueryData (String sql) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }

    // return
    public Cursor GetData (String sql) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Create table CauHoi
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CauHoi (" +
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                " CauHoi VARCHAR(2000)," +
                " CauHoiA VARCHAR(2000)," +
                " CauHoiB VARCHAR(2000)," +
                " CauHoiC VARCHAR(2000)," +
                " CauHoiD VARCHAR(2000)," +
                " soDe INTEGER," +
                " DapAn VARCHAR(10)," +
                " CauCanLuuY VARCHAR(10))");

        // Create table CauHoiSai
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CauHoiSai (" +
                "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "IdCauHoiSai INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE)");
```

and here is my DataBaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.app_onthi_pmp.updatecauhoi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import static com.example.app_onthi_pmp.updatecauhoi.UserDatabaseAdapter.TABLE_NAME;
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CauHoiSai(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,IdCauHoiSai INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE);");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CauHoi(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CauHoi VARCHAR, CauHoiA VARCHAR,CauHoiB VARCHAR,CauHoiC VARCHAR,CauHoiD VARCHAR,soDe INTEGER,DapAn VARCHAR,CauCanLuuY VARCHAR);");
        }catch(Exception er){
            Log.e("Error","exception");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "SEMESTER1");
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(db);
    }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for reading. I solved that problem

Comment: It would be better if you can post your answer to your question.

Comment: in the insertEntry statement, I mistyped the name of my database value. And then I changed the names of the values ​​in insertEntry to match the values ​​of the database, and it worked.

Comment: and i add a statement ```db=openOrCreateDatabase("CauHoi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);``` in my class MainActivity.

Comment: Would you mind clicking the button "Post Your Answer" to post your answer for this question.  It would be better. If other people meet a similar question one day, they can search this question and find out the answer quickly.

Comment: It's helpful for your reputation on Stack overflow and also be helpful for the people to solve same problem in future:)